# How to ease the edges of a volumetric texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, volumetrics

I have a volumetric texture, and I don't know how I can ease the edges of this texture, to rub the "cube shape" of the volumetric texture.

I also need this to be keyframed.

[image]

I tried to use different combinations of gradient texture nodes, transparency node too, but I was not able to rub the edges.

Can you help me ?

Here's the node setup:
[image]

Here's a blend file : [image]

Bye guys ! :)

Comment: Hello :). Not an answer, but you could use a sphere instead of a cube. Then the edges will be softer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using another Shape is indeed not a bad idea. (@Jachym Michal)

But here is a node setup to give you pretty good controll of the density border.
For better visibility I haven't multiplied it with your current density setup yet, but the math node already is sitting in place as you can see.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sweet, learned something new here, thanks :).